# how get xml responce using JAX-WS SOAP handler

Tags: soap, jax-ws, response

I have implemented web service:

```
@WebServiceClient(//parameters//)
@HandlerChain(file = "handlers.xml")
public class MyWebServiceImpl {...}
```

Also I have implemented ObjectFactory with list of classes for creating my requests and responses. For Example class Test.

I need to get xml of response.

I try to use JAX-WS SOAP handler, so I add this `@HandlerChain(file = "handlers.xml")` anotation.
My handlers.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
<handler-chain>
<handler>
<handler-class>java.com.webservice.service.LoggingHandler</handler-class>
</handler>
</handler-chain>
</handler-chains>
```

My LoggingHandler class is:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

public class LoggingHandler implements javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>     {

    public void close(MessageContext messagecontext) {
    }

    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext messagecontext) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc.get (MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
            System.out.println("\nOutbound message:");
        } else {
        System.out.println("\nInbound message:");
        }

        SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();

        try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("soap_responce" + System.currentTimeMillis(), "UTF-8");
        writer.println(message);
        writer.close();
        message.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println("");   // just to add a newline
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in handler: " + e);
    }
    return outboundProperty;   
}
```

}

I have test class which creates request, here are part of code:

```
MyWebServiceImpl impl = new MyWebServiceImpl(url, qName);
    ws = impl.getMyWebServicePort();
Test req = new Test();
```

I suppose to get xml response in file "soap_responce" + System.currentTimeMillis(). But such file isn't even created. Please suggest how to get xml response, I'm new to web services and may do something wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SOAP handlers is IMHO perfectly fine for such a task. I would approach it the same way.

I was able to use your configuration with minor modifications to get the example running. As a result I am able to see generated files. If you can't see them please check whether you check correct path, e.g. using:

```
File file = new File("soap_responce" + System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

What I changed is:

- package from `java.com.webservice.service.LoggingHandler` to `com.webservice.service.LoggingHandler` as packages starting with java are forbidden

Complete project can be found here:
https://github.com/destin/SO-answers/tree/master/SO-how-get-xml-responce-using-jax-ws-soap-handler

org.dpytel.jaxws.jaxws_java_first_jboss.client.Main class shows how I get and execute the web service.

BTW. you don't need to implement client stub and object factory etc when you have WSDL file. You can use `wsimport` tool. You can check how to use it in mentioned project.